# How to solve error about "invalid selector" when using "if statement" in Protractor JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I want to use an invisible element as a condition if it present do X and else do Y.

I've already tried to use by the class of this element as the locator and the ng-model and binding of him but none of them is worked :/

Please your assistance to solve this issue, thanks a lot.

**This is my the problematic test case:**

```
describe('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message', function() {

    var msgBox = expect(element(by.css(".final-container")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
    //var msgBox = element.all(by.css('#main_container > main > div > div > section > div.row.cz-content.inner-content.full-height > div > div.action.ng-scope > footer > form > div.row.form-control.textarea-holder.ng-isolate-scope.ng-hide > textarea'));
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    it('LiveSite - Home Page', function() {
       liveSiteHome();
    });

    if (msgBox === false) {

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Message form', function() {
          browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions-row']//a[.='Leave Your Details']"))), 10000);
          element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions-row']//a[.='Leave Your Details']")).click();
          waitPageToLoad(); 
          expect(element(by.id("new_client_message_message")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
          element(by.css("div.row.mandatory > div.area")).click();
          element(by.id("new_client_message_title")).sendKeys("Automation message");
          element(by.id("new_client_message_message")).sendKeys("I am not logged-in client. Please call me.");
          element(by.id("new_client_message_email")).sendKeys("idanvcita@gmail.com");
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Welcome back for existing client', function() {
          element(by.id("new_client_message_first_name")).click();
          browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("span.welcome-back"))), 10000);
          expect(element(by.css("span.welcome-back")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Messeage Sent', function() {
          element(by.name("commit")).click();
          waitPageToLoad(); 
          expect(element(by.css(".final-container")).isPresen()).toBe(true);t
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Back to home page', function() {
          element(by.css(".standard-button")).click();
          expect(element(by.model("email")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
          browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        });

    } else {

        it('LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Text Area', function() {
          // expect(element(msgBtn.isPresent()).toBe(true);
          element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']/main/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/footer/form/div[2]/textarea")).sendKeys("Hello!\nHow are you?\nHave a good day! :)");
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Message has been sent', function() {
          element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']//button[.='Send']")).click();
          browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']//h2[.='Quick conversation']"))), 10000);
          browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        });

    }

});
```

**This is the element = msgBox:**

```
<a class="btn btn-void btn-with-font-round-icon engage-btn icon-lg brand-theme-before icon-env ng-binding" ng-click="goExternalUrl(contact_url)" ng-bind="truncate(livesite_actions_texts.contact, 22)" title="Leave Your Details">Leave Your Details</a>
```

**This is the error:**

```
c:\automation\tests>protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message
  encountered a declaration exception - fail


Failures:

  1) LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message encountered a declaratio
n exception
   Message:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchersClass' of null
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchersClass' of null
    at promiseMatchers (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:203:38)
    at global.expect (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:221:12)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\msg.js:3:61)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\msg.js:1:63)

Finished in 0.125 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

c:\automation\tests>
```

Comment: you need to isolate the code where the actual error happens . there are several css selectors have been used in your test case, so it is impossible to get the root problem of this error `InvalidSelectorError` at once. try reducing the steps and running them one by one . also you can use browser.pause() to pause the steps , in that way you can identify as to which steps actually gives this error.

Comment: Thanks malik, but I know where this problem happens and it's regarding the IF statement. I've already did some research to find this but I don't know what is the reason for it.. : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var msgBox = expect(element(by.css(".final-container")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Happens outside any `it` declarations.  But all of the Protractor (really webdriver) magic promise resolution happens in the ControlFlow created on each `it`.  So, I don't think this works as you expect.

Second:

```
if (msgBox === false) {
```

Is checking the result of an `expect`, which is a Promise (if anything).  I'm pretty confident its not a boolean.  In any event, you're trying to change which `it` functions will execute, but that requires having executed some protractor code, which isn't really going to work.

It looks like you want to inspect the page, decide which "flavor" it is, and then run different tests for the different flavors (with or without a text box).  This seems like a reasonable thing to want, but I don't think Protractor has a good way of expressing this.  (I think many folks would suggest that you set things up so that your test *knows* which case to expect and that it causes both sets of code to execute.  This conditional approach means a test "passing" may not have exercised all of your code.)

Answer (score 0):

since you are saying that this issue occurs inside the `if` statement , i assume that this issue occurs when accessing **msgBox** . So try using `element.all(by.css('.ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid)'));` instead of `element(by.css(....))`.

or try accessing the element like this

```
var msgBox = element.all(by.css('[ng-click="goExternalUrl(contact_url)"]'));
```

Comment: Thanks again buddy, But it still doesn't work. I've updated the error, the code and the css. please your advise. thanks @malik_curtin

Comment: hmm. are you sure you have the currect css selector here , `('.ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid)'` ? Can you post the html code ?

Comment: what is the name of the element you trying to access by **msgBox** ?

Comment: okay try using like this `element.all(by.css('#main_container > main > div > div > section > div.row.cz-content.inner-content.full-height > div > div.action.ng-scope > footer > form > div.row.form-control.textarea-holder.ng-isolate-scope.ng-hide > textarea'))` or try the way i have specified in my edited answer